# how to kill process and don't see output in console

Tags: linux, bash, console

I am interesting how to kill some process from another console and don't see a printout "killed" in first console as output. I'd like to redirect output to /dev/null in the best case. So here is a simple example what I am gonna achieve:

```
in first console I type:
sleep 30
in second console:
killall -9 sleep
```

And as a result in the first console I get "killed" what I don't want to see.

Comment: Why does the `killed` message (from your shell) bothers you?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to kill the shell first as this is the process which prints the message.

Or you can simply run the command in subshell and redirect the outputs:

```
( sleep 30 ) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Why a subshell? why not `{ sleep 30; } >/dev/null 2>&1`? Also, this is not really a good idea if you want to preserve stdout/stderr of the command (though it's possible with some plumbing). Another option is to turn off job control in the shell where you don't want to see the message with `set +m`.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for best answer I have found this one:

wait command processes the kill signals in this way:

```
kill $!
wait $! 2>/dev/null
```

So as a result "killed" message is redirected to /dev/null or to some pointed out file.